# My text database program "Cannot resolve address of overloaded function"

Tags: c++

I wrote this program with the goal of making it output to a text file. Normally I can do this but I wanted to divide it in to functions and I am bewildered to why I keep getting the error "Statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function". Any help would be greatly appreciated.
http://pastebin.com/JkxC75Cc

Comment: Please try to post minimal code rather than linking to the source.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains this code fragment:

```
operations key;
key.writer;
```

Perhaps you wanted to *call* the `writer` method:

```
key.writer();
```

Comment: Now my error is no matching function to call to operations::writer

Comment: Actually there are several other problems there. Why do you have the `writer` method templated, i.e. why do you have `template <class E>` there? And what's the actual return type you want to support?